# Error when cross compiling Qt 5.0.1 for the Raspberry Pi

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi, raspbian, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to cross compile Qt 5.0.1 (latest release at the moment) for my Raspberry Pi. My set up is as follows:

Operating System: Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit

Cross compiler: Built from crosstool-NG program, using the exact instructions [found here](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/)

Raspberry Pi Operating System: Raspbian Wheezy 2013-02-09 (mounted at /mnt/raspberry-pi-rootfs)

Configure command:

```
./configure -no-pch -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/<myusername>/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi- -sysroot /mnt/raspberry-pi-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5-raspberry-pi -v
```

When I run the configure command, it always fails with the following error:

```
Could not determine the target architecture!

/mnt/raspberry-pi-rootfs/usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
```

Anyone know what this means?

I have tried the latest pre-built Linaro Toolchain cross compiler [from here](https://wiki.linaro.org/WorkingGroups/ToolChain), and Qt at least builds, but any program compiled with it causes SIGILL (illegal instruction) fault as soon as the program runs up, which I guess is because the pre-built cross compler I used is not targeting the right architecture.

**Note:**

I am aware cross compiling is fiendishly difficult, but I'd like to understand more about what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  not sure what the exact cause of this message was, but I managed to sort out by using a pre-buils toolchain for the Raspberry Pi from here:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools